# Does Tensor Shape matter in the input shape of keras model? R-Programming

Tags: r, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

```
library(png)
library(colorspace)

files <- list.files(pattern = ".png$", recursive = TRUE)
filePathFunction <- function(x){
  a <- matrix(nrow=length(x))
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    conc <- c("~/E-books/Coding/Machine Learning with R/Neural Networks/four-shapes",x[i])
    a[i] <- paste(conc, collapse="/")
  }
  return(a)
}


filePaths <- filePathFunction(files)
image(readPNG(filePaths[1]), useRaster=TRUE, axes=FALSE)

set.seed(101)
ind <- sample(nrow(filePaths),round(0.75*nrow(filePaths)),replace=F)
train <- filePaths[ind,]
test <- filePaths[-ind,]
```

This is my code preprocessing code for this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/smeschke/four-shapes/discussion/43879
I'm using deep learning with r and somewhere in the book's example they change the matrix from a 28x28x60000 a 28x28 pixel matrix of pictures for 60000 pictures into a 784*60000 matrix. Something like this:

```
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
train_images <- mnist$train$x
train_images <- array_reshape(train_images, c(60000, 28 * 28))
train_images <- train_images / 255
test_images <- mnist$test$x
test_images <- array_reshape(test_images, c(10000, 28 * 28))
test_images <- test_images / 255

network <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(28*28)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax")
```

does it matter what my input shape and hidden units are to the neural network?

Comment: Depends on the network. For a densely connected network, shape usually won’t matter. For a convolutional net, it absolutely will. This question is probably better suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

For Convolutional networks it matters because depending on number and dimensions of filter/pooling layers(max/avg) you need to decide the input shape. For dense network, theoretically it does not matter.